# Visual Basic 2010 Finding objects at a point on the form

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, object

So I've been doing some programing in visual basic 2010. For my program I need to determine whether there is an object at a point on the main form [for example (20, 35)]. I tried:

```
Dim ObjectFind as object   
ObjectFind = Me.GetChildAtPoint(20, 35)
```

I'm not sure if this works, ObjectFind usually equals {System.Windows.Forms.Form}
So I figured that if ObjectFind doesn't equal {System.Windows.Forms.Form} that would me there's a different object there, so I did:

```
If ObjectFind <> System.Windows.Forms.Form then  
    ' Code is here  
end if
```

But visual basic says that System.Windows.Forms.Form can't be use in a condition.
I've done lots of research and I didn't find much on how to find an object at a point in visual basic.

I also tried:

```
If ObjectFind.Equals(System.Windows.Forms.Form) = false then  
    ' Code is here  
end if
```

I got the same error as before.
Since System.Windows.Forms.Form is the main form I tried:

```
If ObjectFind.Equals(Me) = false then  
    ' Code is here  
end if
```

But then its always false no matter what object is at (20, 35)

In case you not sure my question is: How can I find out if there is an object at a point on the form in visual basic 2010?

Comment: You said, "I need to determine whether there is an object at a point on the main form..."  By object do you mean a control of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you test for object being a certain type in VB.NET:

```
If TypeOf ObjectFind Is System.Windows.Forms.Form then
```

Answer (score 0):

Instad of first if use following:

```
If ObjectFind.GetType() <> GetType(System.Windows.Forms.Form) Then

End If
```

Comment: This approach of doing type comparison did not work for me in a test project. Probably because in my case ObjectFind is derived from a Form, rather than just being a Form. Had to use this: `If ObjectFind.GetType.IsSubclassOf(GetType(Form)) Then`.